# Ref in flatlist items does not return correct PageY position when loading more data in a list

Tags: react-native, dropdown, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to display dropdown below flatlist items. Pagination is implemented in Flatlist, so when i load data for first-page, the dropdown position is calculated accurately. but when i load data for another pages, pageY postion in ref measure method is increased by list size. So due to this dropdown isn't displayed in visible area. I am attaching my code for reference.

this is my render method.

```
render() {
        let { list, } = this.props;
        const {top,listVisibity,articleDropdown} = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>      
                <OptimizedFlatList
                    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
                    windowSize={16}
                    onEndReached={() => this.onEndReached()}
                    nestedScrollEnabled={false}
                    onScrollBeginDrag = {() => this.setState({listVisibity:false})}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 0.01}
                    onMomentumScrollBegin={() => { this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false; }}
                    data={list}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => this._renderItem(item)}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    style={{ flexGrow: 1}}
                    ListFooterComponent={this.footer}
                />
 
</view>

}
```

And here is list and sublist rendering

```
 _renderItem = item => {
        return (    
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ShadowView style={styles.shadowStyle}>
                    <View style={styles.listItem} >
                        <View style={{ flex: 0.6, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            <Image
                                source={constants.images.dot}
                                style={{ alignSelf: 'center', width: RFValue(12), resizeMode: 'contain', marginRight: 10 }}
                            />
                            <Highlighter
                                highlightStyle={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
                                searchWords={[this.props.searchedText]}
                                textToHighlight= {item.name.toUpperCase()+" ("+item.topics.length+")"}
                                style={{ color: "#0C3C7F", alignSelf: 'center', fontWeight: '500', fontFamily:constants.fontFamily.SFProDisplay }}
                                />
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ flex: 0.4}}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                this.updateSelection(item)
                            }}>
                                {item.isExpanded ? <Image
                                        source={constants.images.dropdownArrow}
                                        style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end', resizeMode: 'contain' }}
                                    /> :
                                    <Image
                                        source={constants.images.arrowUp}
                                        style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end', resizeMode: 'contain' }}
                                    />
                                }
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ShadowView>    
                {this.renderSubList(item)}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

```
renderSubList = (item) => {
        
        return  <Collapsible collapsed={!item.isExpanded}>
            <FlatList
                data={item.topics} 
                scrollEnabled={false}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <ShadowView style={item.isSelected? styles.topicShadowStyle_1:styles.topicShadowStyle}> 
                       <View ref={ref => this.parentView = ref}
                       onLayout={(event) => {
                       
                        this.find_dimesions(event.nativeEvent.layout) }}
                       style={[{flexDirection: 'row'}, item.isSelected ? { borderColor: constants.colors.lightBlue, borderTopLeftRadius: 10,borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,borderRadius:8, borderWidth: 2 } : {}]}>
                            {(item.fullTextUrl!=null && item.fullTextUrl!='') || (item.pdfLink!=null && item.pdfLink!='') ?
                                <View style={{ width: width * 4 / 100, backgroundColor: constants.colors.lightBlue, borderTopLeftRadius: 8, borderBottomLeftRadius: 8 }}></View>:
                                <View style={{ width: width * 4 / 100, backgroundColor: constants.colors.lightGray_1, borderTopLeftRadius: 8, borderBottomLeftRadius: 8 }}></View>
                            }
                            <View  style={{ width: '95%' }}>
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onLongPress={() => this.props.updateShowSelectedIcon(item)} onPress={() => this.props.showDetails(item)}>
                                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: '100%' }}>
                                        <View style={{ flex: 1, marginHorizontal: width * 3 / 100, marginVertical: height * 1.5 / 100, backgroundColor: constants.colors.white }}>
                                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: '100%' }}>
                                                <View style={{ alignContent: 'flex-start', width: '65%' }}>
                                                <Highlighter
                                                    highlightStyle={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
                                                    searchWords={[this.props.searchedText]}
                                                    textToHighlight= {item.journal.toUpperCase()}
                                                    style={styles.jurnalTitle}
                                                    numberOfLines={2}
                                                />
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={{ alignContent: 'flex-end', width: '35%', }}>
                                                    <Text style={styles.dateStyle} >{item.date}</Text>
                                                </View>   
                                            </View>
                                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: '100%', marginTop: height * 1 / 100 }}>
                                                <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-start', width: '70%' }}>
                                                    <Highlighter
                                                        highlightStyle={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
                                                        searchWords={[this.props.searchedText]}
                                                        textToHighlight= {item.article}
                                                        style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: constants.colors.black_1, alignContent: 'flex-start' }}
                                                        numberOfLines={2}
                                                    />
                                                </View>
                                                {!this.props.showSelectedIcon?
                                                    <View
                                                    ref={(ref) => { this.rowRefs[item.id] = ref; }}
                                                 //   ref={ref => this[`myView${item.id}`]=ref}
                                                    onLayout={(event) => { 
                                                        const {x, y, width, height} =event.nativeEvent.layout
                                                    }}
                                                    style={{position:'relative', alignItems: 'flex-end', width: '30%' }}>
                                                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: RFValue(20), width: RFValue(20) }} 
                                                        onPress={() => this.calculateIconPosition(item)}>
                                                            {(item.fullTextUrl!=null && item.fullTextUrl!='') || (item.pdfLink!=null && item.pdfLink!='') ?
                                                                <Image
                                                                    source={constants.images.Oval}
                                                                    style={{ height: RFValue(20), width: RFValue(20) }}
                                                                />:
                                                                <Image
                                                                    source={constants.images.dropdown}
                                                                    style={{ height: RFValue(20), width: RFValue(20) }}
                                                                />
                                                            }
                                                    </TouchableOpacity>   
                                                        {/* { <View  onLayout={(event) => { 
                                                                const {x, y, width, height} =event.nativeEvent.layout
                                                                console.log(y)
                                                        }} > </View>} */}
                                                 </View>:
                                                    <View
                                                        style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', width: '30%' }}>
                                                         {item.isSelected? 
                                                                <Image
                                                                    source={constants.images.selected}
                                                                    style={{ height: RFValue(20), width: RFValue(20) }}
                                                                />:
                                                            <Image
                                                                source={constants.images.unselect}
                                                                style={{ height: RFValue(20), width: RFValue(20) }}
                                                            />
                                                        }
                                                    </View>
                                                }
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                {this.renderNotesView(item)}
                            </View>
                        </View> 
                    </ShadowView>
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
        </Collapsible>
    }
```

Item Measurement Method Call

```
calculateIconPosition = (item) => {
        this.rowRefs[item.id].measure( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
            console.log("=================PY=====================")
            console.log(py)        
        })
        
    }
```

Is there any way to get exact pageY position in flat list.